deploy feature version of npm package as pre release
I have a react project that is bundled with tsbuild and publish to npm package through azure devOps. Recently, noticed when someone tried to install the package by running
yarn add packageName --latest

it installs the latest deployed version even though it is from the feature branch. For exampe:
branch-3

But what we would like to do is not installed that feature version but install the version that are deployed from the master branch.
Can someone guide me how to achieve this.
We are actually deploying the npm package to azure artificats through auzre devOps pipeline. And here is some examples that what we are doing:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm package version'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(${{parameters.Publish}}, true))
  inputs:
    workingDir: ${{ parameters.Directory }}
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: '--no-git-tag-version version ${{ parameters.Version }}'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm publish'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(${{parameters.Publish}}, true))
  inputs:
    workingDir: ${{ parameters.Directory }}
    command: 'publish'
    publishRegistry: 'useFeed'
    publishFeed: ${{ parameters.Feed }}


What do you mean by publish to npm package through Azure DevOps? Do you mean you use Azure Pipelines to publish npm packages to Azure Artifacts feed or any other package source provider like npmjs.com? If yes, can you share your pipeline YAML definition to help understand your workflow? Would you specify how those packages werre published currently to differentiate the packages that was built and packed with the code from different branches?

Yes, we are pulishing the npm package to azure artifacts through the azure devOps pipeline. I edited the ansers with the task examples that we are doing at the moment.

The latest version of the package is determined by the tag latest. It applies automatically unless you use the option --tag. Reading the npm docs:

Publishing a package sets the latest tag to the published version unless the --tag option is used. For example, npm publish --tag=beta.


so is it then when publishing from the feature branch, we should add some tag and publishing from the master branch there should't be any tag used. Just trying to understand where and I should make the changes

You publish from the master branch using your usual practice, which supposedly attaches the tag 'last' to each publish, letting survive only the last one. For feature branches use the key '--tag' with the desired tag name. It may reflect the feature name, for example. So you will be able to install the package that you need: 'npm i package-name@feature-tag-name'.

Based on the update, it seemed that your pipeline was able to run and build the code from different branches of your repo and publish the npm package into the Azure Artifacts Feed. The only difference was the package version that was set.
For this, you may try and use the command below to install the expected package, whose version was built with the code in the master branch.
npm install mypackage@1.0.0

Please also get prepared to Connect to a feed first.
